# IISNode and/or nodemon for node.js on Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, iisnode, nodemon

If I already use [IISNode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) under Windows for my node.js application (locally during development and on production Windows hosting as well), should I care about [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) (or any similar "watch files for changes and restart node.exe if any" modules)?

Comment: I'd also like to know that...it seems that sometimes IIS refreshes, but sometimes it doesn't. Have you found out yet @Sevenate ?

Comment: @AndréLucas, not yet, but for me IISNode do the job just fine, that is why I'm wondering if I miss something here.

Comment: The only issue I'm getting is with stylus compiling. IIS doesn't recompile, so I had to do it manually everytime...

Comment: @AndréLucas, that is correct - I use IISNode mostly just to maintain the Node up and running the application, i.e. restart it if the process terminates because of for some error. If you need any automatic CSS/JS preprocessing take a look at http://gruntjs.com

Answer (score 1):

If you want iisnode to use nodemon instead of node, add the following to your web.config file under `<system.webServer>`:

`<iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;C:\path_to_node_on_your_system\node_modules\.bin\nodemon.cmd&quot;" />`